# Call jQuery Function after ajax load

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

So, the thing is i'm trying to import a slider with ajax, the slider works if you access the page directly:

http:// www.iloja.pt/ajaxload/ipod.php

if you try to access iloja.pt and click "reparações" and after that click "iPod" it calls the ipod.php page but the slider doesn't work. I tried to include the js files in many ways but the

**i know i have to use bind function, but don't know how to do it.**

Comment: Keep all your JS on the parent page and run any jQuery plugins on the success callback of the ajax call.

Comment: @Jleagle But i don't want to load the js files needed by the slider before the slider is called, it will add size to the page load unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some javascript errors, specifically:

"animation is not defined"

Comment: That animation(); is not related with the slider. Thanks.

Comment: The javascript error can prevent other javascript from being executed. I would fit that error first.

Comment: the error is now inexistent. The problem remains. Any more tips?

Comment: The slider no longer works on http://www.iloja.pt/ajaxload/ipod.php. You need to include the jQuery plugin for ContentSlider.

Comment: now it works on that address, but the debuger tells me that on index the js files aren't being loaded:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://www.iloja.pt/js/jquery.ennui.contentslider.js?_=1326823441414Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Looks like that js file does not exist. Check your reference. Also, the path to your css file has an extra folder in it (css/css) which is why that isn't showing up.

Answer (score 0):

You have many errors in that page, see Javascript console on Chrome or Firebug on Firefox.
In particular I can see this errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) [http://www.iloja.pt/js/jquery.ennui.contentslider.js?_=1326816532863]
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ContentSlider'
```

your problem is that the browser can't load the contentslider.js library so you have an exception when using ContentSlider Method.

Try to fix the loading of the js.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the async: 'false' parameter to your ajax call, that way it should load your code entirely before doing anything else...